# Array of forms in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have following requirement like:

In template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
  <form [formGroup]="item.name">
    <input type="text" formControlName="release" />
    <button >Add more input box</button>
  </form>  
</div>
```

In typescript:

it should be like form[] = ["form1","form2"];
    then access this form array forms controls.

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I mean the correct syntax. In typescript, how array will be created and how I will be accessing each forms. In google I can find only one form with array of dynamic fields but not array of forms with array of fields.